# Cairo convert to monochrome?

Tags: cairo

Is there a straightforward way of converting a Cairo RGB surface to 1 bit monochrome (FORMAT_A1) using operators, or does it require iterating through all the pixels?

There are numerous examples of converting to greyscale, where the hue and saturation are discarded and only the luminosity of the RGB channels is kept.  The problem is that in A1 surfaces the 1 bit data comes from the alpha channel, and I can't find any method for translating luminosity (in the RGB channels) to alpha.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an image to grayscale with Cairo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373489/how-to-convert-an-image-to-grayscale-with-cairo)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  Greyscale is still processed as RGB values which is  different than monochrome. (1 bit packed alpha channel only)

Comment: Ah, okay. I know how to turn an alpha channel into color channel, but for the other direction I have no idea.